# Is there a way to generate a schema.graphql file from a datamodel.prisma file?

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm creating a back-end using the Prisma-cli, which automatically creates the datamodel.prisma file. From looking at Prisma's official examples[1], it seems like they all have a schema.graphql file as well. Anyone know if there's a way to generate a schema.graphql file from a datamodel.prisma file (and then just fill in the Mutation and Query types)?

It just seems repetitive if you had to manually create and maintain both files since they're very similar.

[1]https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/master/typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm seems this isn't possible, but what I really like of this (have separated files) is that from `schema.graphql` you can define wich should be accesible for the client.

For example if you have User model, you can overwrite it to hide password or things like that.

What I already do in my `schema.graphql` is import the entire generated `prisma.schema`: `# import * from "./generated/prisma.graphql"`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[Checkout here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVdkg.png) - Create a .graphqlconfig file in the root of your project. Paste
the below config And also create src/generated folder. Run the cmd
after installing CLI: graphql get-schema -p prisma.

```
{
    "projects": {
        "prisma": {
            "schemaPath": "src/generated/prisma.graphql",
            "extensions": {
                "endpoints": {
                    "default": "http://localhost:4466"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```